# Append Authorization Header Before Authorizing Web Sockets

Tags: c#, websocket, .net-core, signalr

I'm in the process of refactoring my API to use the built in .Net authentication instead of IdentityServer4

In my old code I would append the authentication token to the websocket address and inject a header using the middleware

```
public class SignalRQueryStringAuthMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public SignalRQueryStringAuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    // Convert incomming qs auth token to a Authorization header so the rest of the chain
    // can authorize the request correctly
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Query.TryGetValue("A5S0kT0k", out var token))
        {
            context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.First());
        }
         await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

I can see that my middleware is being executed as expected an appending the proper authorization Header.

However in my startup my Authorization never seems to be called and it moves directly to connecting to the websocket'

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(cfg => {
        cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        cfg.SaveToken = true;

        cfg.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = async (ctx) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ctx.Token);
            },

            OnTokenValidated = async (ctx) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("BreakPoint");
            },

            OnAuthenticationFailed = async (ctx) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Breakpoint");
            }
        };

        cfg.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
    });
```

Here is the order of execution of my pipeline in the configure

```
app.UseSignalRQueryStringAuth();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<DefaultServiceHubBase<MessageDTO>>("/messages");
    routes.MapHub<DefaultServiceHubBase<ConversationDTO>>("/conversations");
    routes.MapHub<InMemoryHub<UserLocationDTO>>("/user-locations");
});
```

I configure my pipeline so that the middleware is hit first but the authentication I can never hit any of my breakpoint in the JWTBearer section,  However if I make a standard HttpRequest everything works fine?

My `OnMessageReceived` is ignored and it goes directly to the onconnect function in my hub why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but it turns out I need to added a default challenge schema as well

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    // Identity made Cookie authentication the default.
    // However, we want JWT Bearer Auth to be the default.
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
```

I found this in the [Signalr Authentication Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-2.2)